# Como alterar o texto de um botão ao submeter um formulário?

Tags: php, jquery

Com o código abaixo, o botão de enviar o formulário deveria mudar de texto para "Carregando..." ao ser pressionado, mas isso não acontece. Porquê?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Troca Games - Games com economia</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("form").submit(function(){
       $("#bt_login").attr("value","Carregando...");  
     });
   });
 </script>
</head> 
<body>
<div style="padding:15px; text-align:center">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="100%"/>
    <br/>
    
    <?php 
  if($_GET['access'])
   echo '<div class="login_failed"><h3>Usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)</h3></div>'
   ?>
    
    <form action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="post" rel="external" name="fm_login" class="login" >
        <input name="usuario_usu" type="text" placeholder="Usuário" >
        <input name="senha_usu" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
        <input type="submit" name="bt_login" id="bt_login" value="Entrar" />
    </form>
    <p style="font-size:20px">Não possui conta? <a href="cadastro.php">Cadastre-se!</a></p>
    <br />
    <img src="images/login_facebook.jpg" width="100%"/>
    <img src="images/login_google.jpg" width="100%"/>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual o problema do código? Clique em [edit] e adicione mais informações.

Comment: Podia tentar explicar seu problema, ai ficaria mais fácil ajudar. ;)

Comment: Demetrius, eu editei sua pergunta pra tentar clarificar um pouco mais, confere aí se é esse mesmo  o problema, e se não for pode clicar em reverter edição. Mas você poderia explicar um pouco melhor, e também seria legal saber qual o erro que vc recebe no console do navegador...

Comment: Submeta o formulário via AJAX e manipule o texto dentro dos eventos do AJAX, não tem erro.

Comment: Oi, @Demetrius. Pus uma resposta com um demo no CODEPEN, pois os snippets aqui do SOpt tem uma limitação ao uso de forms. Dê uma olhadinha na questão de além de mudar o texto, desabilitar o botão também.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode alterar com o metodo text assim:

```js
$("#btn").text("Carregando...");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="btn" id="btn">Stack Overflow</button>
```

No seu caso seria:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $("#bt_login").text("Carregando...");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Para jQuery acima de 1.6, é recomendável o uso do `prop` no lugar de `attr`.

Segue um exemplo que além de mudar o texto, desabilita o botão para evitar mais de um envio em seguida:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    $('#bt_login').prop('value', 'Enviando...').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/jWPvjV?editors=101)**.

**Se for usar com Ajax,** lembre-se de colocar um `.prop('disabled', false);` caso o retorno dê erro, senão a pessoa perde o conteúdo do formulário e não tem como tentar novo envio em caso de falha.

Mesmo com um formulário comum, talvez seja o caso de reativar o botão com um timer depois de alguns segundos, pelo mesmo motivo explicado acima.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bt_login').val('Carregando...');
```